# Google Sheets - How to join cells into one that meet a condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like create a new sheet in my document and combine all values in Products sheet from column A (from A2) into one on the new sheet, when Current Stock (calculated) is greater than 1 (preferably only non blank cells):

[image]

Currently I am using formula:

```
=JOIN(";",Products!A2:A,"")
```

How can I add here check for Current Stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-

```
=JOIN(";",FILTER(Products!A2:A,Products!H2:H>0))
```

`H2:H>0` will filter out non blank number values cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=JOIN(";",FILTER(Products!A2:A,LEN(Products!H2:H)))
```

the condition is for lenght > 0, you can modify with what you want.

Bye